# draw free draw polygons angular google maps

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, angular-google-maps

I was looking at the free-draw-polygons example, as that is something i currently need, and looks pretty neat.

However I was "porting" the code into my own controller and i did not quite get why it seemed so "complicated" needing, factory, services, etc so I though to keep it to bare minimum and have the button in the $templateCache, calling directly a method in the scope for calling: "$scope.map.draw()" and "$scope.map.polys = [];".

However when I click draw, I get "$scope.map.draw is not a function" because it's undefined by default.
Can someone explain me why?

Comment: It was because i called $scope.map.draw() before map was ready.  uiGmapIsReady passes a promise callback of map which we can use to check if map is ready like `uiGmapIsReady.promise().then(function (map) {
         $scope.map.draw()
});`